# Manipulação de $_GET com quebra de linha

Tags: php

Estou usando a Biblioteca GD, tenho o código abaixo e quero colocar uma quebra de linha `$texto = "primeira linha\nsegunda linha";`, porém precisa passar pelo `$get`.

O que quero dizer com passar pelo `$get` é que se você substituir a linha

```
$texto = $_GET['texto'];
```

por

```
$texto = "linha1\n linha2";
```

no arquivo `img.php` o `\n` vai quebrar a linha e usando o form no `method get` o texto fica na mesma linha.

Como corrigir isso?

**`index.php`**

```
<?php $go = isset($_GET['texto'])?$_GET['texto']:"primeira linha\nsegunda linha";?>
   <form method="get">
   <input name="texto" type="text" value="<?php echo $go ?>" size="100"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Criar imagem" />
   </form>
   <img src="img.php?texto=<?php echo $go ?>"  />
```

**`img.php`**

```
<?php
$tamfonte = 25;
$fonte = 'verdana.ttf';
$texto = $_GET['texto'];
$img = imagettfbbox($tamfonte, 0, $fonte, $texto);
$largura = "600";
$altura = "400";
$imagem = imagecreate($largura, $altura);
imagecolorallocate($imagem, 255, 255, 255);
$corfonte = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 0, 0, 0);
imagefttext($imagem, $tamfonte, 0, 0, abs($img[5]), $corfonte, $fonte, $texto);
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
imagejpeg($imagem, NULL, 100);  ?>
```

Comment: @brasofilo - O que eu quis dizer passar pelo $get foi que se vc substituir a linha $texto = $_GET['texto']; por essa $texto = "linha1\n linha2"; no arquivo img.php o \n vai quebrar a linha e usando oform no method get o texto fica na mesma linha. esse comando  "imagecreate( int_x size,int y_size);" tem a ver com GD o termo na perguta é porque usei ele é isso!

Answer (score 2):

Para que possas passar via `$_GET` quebras de linha ou outros caracteres não-alfanuméricos, deves codificar o valor para ficar *URL safe*.

Em PHP podes fazer uso da função [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```php
$string = "primeira linha\nsegunda linha";

$url = "http://www.example.com/?texto=".urlencode($string);

echo $url; // http://www.example.com/?texto=primeira+linha%0Asegunda+linha
```

O PHP faz o *decode* de forma automática quando coloca os valores dentro da `$_GET` pelo que a tua quebra de linha deverá estar presente quando acedes a `$_GET['texto']`.

Answer (score 1):

Para apresentar 2 linhas tem que quebrar a string e repetir a criação de texto. Ou seja qualquer coisa deste tipo:

```
<?php

$tamfonte = 25;
$fonte = 'verdana.ttf';

$texto = explode("qualquer_separador", $_GET['texto']);


$largura = "600";
$altura = "400";

$imagem = imagecreate($largura, $altura);
imagecolorallocate($imagem, 255, 255, 255);
$corfonte = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 0, 0, 0);

$img = imagettfbbox($tamfonte, 0, $fonte, $texto[0]);

imagefttext($imagem, $tamfonte, 0, 0, abs($img[5]), $corfonte, $fonte, $texto[0]);


$img2 = imagettfbbox($tamfonte, 0, $fonte, $texto[1]);

imagefttext($imagem, $tamfonte, 0, 0, abs($img2[5]), $corfonte, $fonte, $texto[1]);

header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
imagejpeg($imagem, NULL, 100);  

?>
```

**Nota: Este é apenas o conceito, não fiz os cálculos do posicionamento das frases porque não sei onde as quer colocar. Assim como está vão ficar uma em cima da outra.**